# Find a running process in a specific directory

Tags: process, winetricks

I was trying to install winetricks, and I did `sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6` to install necessary tools as suggested [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks).

But the installation isn't completing and I'm stuck at this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/s/.wine terminate
------------------------------------------------------
```

So I knew of a handy program called [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)  by Microsoft which would allow me to see running processes by directory (If I remember correctly), Now that I've switched to Linux, I only have `ps -A | grep wine` which doesn't help.

So any ideas to find what's running in the `/home/s/.wine` directory so I could kill it?

### UPDATE:

Output of `ps -aux | grep wine`:

```
s          762  1.9  0.0  29524 12632 ?        Ss   15:27   3:20 /opt/wine-stable/bin/wineserver
s          771  0.0  0.0 2094408 12632 ?       Sl   15:27   0:02 C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe
s          786  0.0  0.0 2082280 12096 ?       Sl   15:27   0:00 C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe
s        21711  0.0  0.0   5724  2860 pts/2    S+   18:11   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/winetricks corefonts vcrun6
s        22281  0.0  0.0   5724  2364 pts/2    S+   18:11   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/winetricks corefonts vcrun6
s        22503  0.0  0.0  19076  2252 pts/2    S+   18:11   0:00 /usr/bin/wineserver -w
s        24138  0.0  0.0  15760  1088 pts/0    S+   18:16   0:00 grep --color=auto wine
```

I think winedevice.exe is running because of the running installation of winetricks, so at this point I can't kill any process, they all seem to be related to winetricks.

Output of `fuser -c ~/.wine`:

```
/home/s/.wine:         762   768c   771c   780c   786c   793c   799cm   801cm  1703cm  1792m  1844c  1845cm  1846cm  1847cm  1849cm  1853cm  1854c  1856cm  1858cm  1859cm  1860c  1861cm  1874cm  1875c  1892cm  1893c  1895cm  1913cm  1914cm  1935c  1968m  1972m  2028c  2035cm  2052c  2058c  2059cm  2061cm  2063cm  2064cm  2105m  2109m  2117m  2188c  2189cm  2193c  2194cm  2208c  2209c  2250c  2259c  2260cm  2322c  2691cm  2697c  2698c  2704m  2710m  2765c  2775c  2803m  2836m  2880m  2881m  2979m  3010m  3037m  3079m  3140m  5531m  8508m  9575m  9793m  9798m  9893m  9962c  9964c 10034m 14449m 15791m 15808m 16059m 16245cm 19583m 20595m 21711c 22281c 22913cm 23829m 24077c 25165m 27037c 28166m 28798m 28978m 30484m 31762m
```

Nothing that can help me here ofc, to many PID's.

Output of `lsof ~/.wine`:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
wineserve 762    s    4r   DIR   8,19     4096 7471194 /home/s/.wine
```

wineserver is again, called up by winetricks installation.

**UPDATE2:**

Output of `pstree -pa 21711`:

```
winetricks,21711 /usr/local/bin/winetricks corefonts vcrun6
  └─winetricks,22281 /usr/local/bin/winetricks corefonts vcrun6
      └─wineserver,22503 -w
```

I must add, to troubleshoot, I tried installing both wine 3.0 and winetricks on a virtual machine, and at this point, yes, winetricks should have prompted me with a GUI box to install vcredist, but on my current user, it just hangs right before that.

Full output of `winetricks corefonts vcrun6`:

```
------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20171222-next - sha256sum: 42145d6905db38265a598459268eb3ba9115a6e582f464684e8fbd62018d5359 with wine-3.0 and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call corefonts
Executing load_corefonts 
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_corefonts /home/s/.cache/winetricks/corefonts/arial32.exe
Executing cp -f /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_corefonts/Arial.TTF /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/Fonts/arial.ttf
Executing cp -f /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_corefonts/Arialbi.TTF /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/Fonts/arialbi.ttf
Executing cp -f /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_corefonts/Arialbd.TTF /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/Fonts/arialbd.ttf
Executing cp -f /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_corefonts/Ariali.TTF /home/s/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/Fonts/ariali.ttf
------------------------------------------------------
Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/s/.wine terminate
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I could simple restart the OS, but nah... I want to learn how to resolve the issue instead.

Comment: `ps -aux | grep wine` might help.

Comment: Either of `fuser` and `lsof` can be used to see which process using that directory

Comment: Add the output of `pstree -pa 21711` ... is it possible that Winetricks is telling you that it is waiting for *the wine process it started* to terminate, possible after you agree to some EULA or something opened by the exe?

Comment: From the pstree output, it looks like the ~700 PID processes are independent of whatever you started.